# LD_LIBRARY_PATH not working

Tags: linux, unix, linker, linker-errors, dynamic-linking

One of my binaries requires `libfoo.so` (which resides in `/dir/libfoo`) and I can't figure out how to link against it by setting an environment variable. I tried the two following solutions:

`export LD_FLAG='-L/dir/libfoo/'`
`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH='-L/dir/libfoo/'`

but when I run `ldd ./mybin` I see `libfoo.so.0 => not found` among other libs that are found.

I can, however, successfully link when I use this: `/lib/ld-linux.so.2 --library-path /dir/libfoo ./mybin`

I'm running Ubuntu 13.10 server x86

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-L` is a gcc flag, and gcc is not involved in this process. Just do

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH='/dir/libfoo/'
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that -L is a gcc flag - I'm trying to run the program not compile it :)

Answer (score 2):

You have passed -L flag to LD_LIBRARY_PATH this is wrong instead remove -L from LD_LIBRARY_PATH

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/dir/libfoo/
```

Also refer http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html for linker/loader specification